# Calculating amount of generated items at given time

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to come up with a formula where given time I can get the amount of "items" available, but my math is not advanced enough to figure it out myself, so I'm asking people smarter than me for help.

I have three items: $A$, $B$ and $C$

- Amount of $A$ is constant. It is always $1$.
- $A$ produces $B$ at a constant rate. $1  \ B$ every second.
- $B$ produces $C$ at a constant rate. $1\ C$ every $2$ seconds.

Where I am at the moment:

1. I understand that amount of $B$ grows linearly because $A$ produces
   $1  \ B$ every second and there is never more than one $A$.
2. But amount of $C$ grows exponentially, because at some point we have several $B$s producing $C$s every $2$ seconds.

What I'm failing at is coming up with a formula that given time can give me the amount of $C$s.

And if I take this further and decide that $C$ produces $D$ at constant rate. How would the formula have to be extended to support that?

Comment: It would be tremendously useful to just start calculating the values. At $t=0$, you have one $A$ and nothing else. At $t=1$, the $A$ generates one $B$ ... and so forth. Perhaps after some time steps you will see a pattern.

Comment: I have used excel to make sense of it and I have also written a script that calculates it by "simulating" it. But I'd like to understand how the same result can be achieved mathematically.

Comment: Idea: consider how many $C$'s are produced at a given time step. I made a drawing and I figured out that starting from $t=0$, the number of $C$'s that are produced is
$$
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, \ldots
$$
(https://oeis.org/A004526) Notice that the $B$'s that are produced on an odd time step only produce a $C$ at an odd step, and the $B$'s that are produced on an even time step produce a $C$ at an odd step. This generates the effect where the same number is repeated twice.

Comment: The [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) for $C$ is $C(t + 2) - C(t) = B(t) = t$ (all B's existing at time $t$ contribute once and B's appearing at time $t + 1$ do not contribute). The solution is $C(t) = (2 t (t - 2) + 1 - (-1)^t)/8$.